# Values are not showing when accessing listBox from other project but in the same solution?

Tags: c#

I am trying to show lisBox values of one project in listBox of another project. I have added DLL as well. I can access that listBox in the 2nd project. But when I run the project I get empty listBox and debugger shows that values were passed from the project but values are not showing in listBox of 2nd project. Please help me.

Comment: Hey Syed. Could you please mark the check sign on the answer if it solved your question. Thanks!

Comment: No, it didn't. I am trying to come up with code.

Answer (score 1):

If the listBox comes full from the other project then the problem must be assigning the values from one listBox to the other. I do not know how you do that since you did not include code but you can try the following code that copies the ingredients of a listBox1 to listBox2:

```
object[] itemList= new object[listBox1.Items.Count]; 
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(itemList, 0);
listBox2.Items.AddRange(itemList);
```

Good luck!